# Enabling moderncv page numbering

Tags: page-numbering, templates, moderncv, cv

I'm wondering how to enable the page numbering in `moderncv`. The default option doesn't show the page numbers.

---

EDIT

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Immagini/} }

\begin{document}
here there is some text    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always post a **useful** [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): as it is, `graphicx` and `\graphicspath` are not relevant with respect to your question, while -for successful compilation- `\name{}{}` is required.

Comment: Hello AlessandroCuttin and Mensch, thank you very much for your elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fancyhdr`.
With the option of the command `\fancyfoot` you can control the positioning of the page number in the footer

- `L` on the left
- `R` on the right
- `C` in the center

As the argument of the command you can simply give `\thepage`.
This results in

```
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
```

You can also achieve something something more elaborated.
For example, using the package `lastpage` you can print something like *page 1 of 5*, by defining the footer in the following way:

```
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

Or (something that I do), you can print in the footer the consent to the personal data processing (when needed).

In the following MWE you can chose between the two

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % only page number
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}}

\name{John}{Doe}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Page number only:

[image]

Page *1 of n*:

[image]

Comment: can you show me also an example with lastpage please?

Comment: Sure! have a look at the most recent edit

Comment: Thank you so much @AlessandroCuttin

Comment: You are welcome! remember also to [upvote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up)/[accept](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) the answers that helped you the most ;)

Answer (score 2):

In your used style `classic` is no footer inserted, it is simply not part of the design of the page or CV.

In style `casual` an footer, including pagenumber and personal datas, is inserted and part of the layout of that style. Then package `fancyhdr` is used.

To get a pagenumber in `classic` style you can simply load and use `fancyhdr` like:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Immagini/} }

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % <=============================================== loading package
\pagestyle{plain} % <=================================================== choosing style
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % <============================================= adding page number

\name{John}{Doe}


\begin{document}

here there is some text    
\end{document}
```

with the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Please see that command `\nopagenumbers{}` is only working with style `casual` ...

Answer (score 0):

Pagenumbering is automatically done in `moderncv`.
If `\nopagenumbers{}` is not commented out, make sure that   `\setlength{\footskip}{100pt}` has the proper value for the page numbers to be shown, otherwise if the value---in this case 100pt---is too large the page numbers will "drop out" of the paper.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! As far as I know (please see my answer to this question) pagenumbering is only done in style casual automatically. Or is there a newer version of moderncv including the numbering?